# Connect Datafiniti API to R (Translate Python Code to R)

Tags: python, r, api

I am looking to connect the Datafiniti API in R. I have been able to connect to it in Python thanks to some of the information they have published, but as a beginner, am unable to translate this code to R. Through research on SO so far, I believe I will need to use `GET` but am not sure how to incorporate `request_headers` and `request_data` section from the Python Code. Below I have typed what the code looks like in Python. Any suggestions on how I can change this Python code to make it suitable for R?

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import json

# Set your API parameters here.
API_token = token
format = 'JSON'
Query = query
num_records = 2
download = False

request_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
request_data = {
    'query': Query,
    'format': format,
    'num_records': num_records,
    'download': download
}

# Make the API call.
r = requests.post('https://api.datafiniti.co/v4/properties/search',json=request_data,headers=request_headers);

# Do something with the response.
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.content)
else:
    print('Request failed')
```

This is what I have tried in R so far (hasn't worked):

```
API_token <-  token
format <- 'JSON'
Query <- query
num_records <- 2
download <- FALSE

request_headers = paste(
  "'Authorization':", 'Bearer ', API_token,
  "'Content-Type':", "'application/json'"
)


request_data <- list('query'= Query, 'format'= format, 'num_records'=num_records, 'download'=download)

path <- "https://api.datafiniti.co/v4/properties/search"

GET(
  url = path,
  query= query,
  content_type_json(),
  add_headers(request_headers)
)
```